# Oracle E-Business Suite: finding dependent objects in file system

Tags: oracle, object

I have a seemingly simple task in oracle e-business suite to accomplish. I need to extend an object to add an additional field from the database. (In this case, supplier's department needs to appear in a datagrid)

I've found a couple of sites and some documentation that tells you *how* this works (updating a view object, updating a Java class, recompiling and ftp-ing the files back to the server). The problem is every tutorial I've seen so far makes the assumption you already *know* where the impacted files are.

I'm struggling with trying to figure out what files I need from my server. I've looked at the **About this page** link which I think points me in the right direction, but I've only found one object.

Any thoughts on how I can find the files I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find all dependent objects of the base Oracle Application page you wish to extend, use the **"About this page"** link shown at the bottom-left corner of the base page. The link renders the About page which displays page definition, current session, and technology stack information for that base page. If you do not see the "About this page" link, verify that the `FND_DIAGNOSTICS` profile option is enabled.

Find the VO Object name from the `View Object` column. Click on it to view the `SQL` query behind the VO. Next You will have to create a new View Object that contains your extended code. Create a directory structure so that you can copy the existing VO from the App server into it. To get the existing VO from `$JAVA_TOP`

Log on to App server (get with the sys admin to better understand your environment)-

1.`cd $JAVA_TOP/oracle/apps/<xxx>` (where xxx is your product tops directory).

2.`tar -cvf <xxx>_top.tar xxx..` repeat for as many modules as you might need.

3.FTP each `.tar` file to `\jdevhome\jdev\myclasses`.

4.Extract each .tar file in the `\jdevhome\jdev\myclasses` and  `\jdevhome\jdev\myprojects` directories.